# Topology of Spectra of integral closure.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a integral domain of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $\tilde A$ be the integral closure of $A$. Can we show $\{D(f)|f\in A\}$ is a topological basis of $\operatorname{Spec} \tilde A$? (I actually want to show all open sets of $\operatorname{Spec} \tilde A$ are of the form $\pi^{-1}{V}$ where $V$ is a open set of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\pi$ is the canonical map $\operatorname{Spec} \tilde A\to\operatorname{Spec} A$) Could you provide any help? Thanks!

Comment: This is false (consider the normalization of the nodal cubic) - why do you want to prove this result?

Comment: @KReiser Well, this is because I have read your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4312847/hartshorne-exercise-ii-6-9a-picard-group-of-a-singular-curve), but I can't see if you don't have this property how could you strictly prove $\mathscr K^*/\pi_*\mathcal O_{\tilde{X}}^*=\operatorname{Ca.div}\tilde X$. Could you explain it more explicitly?

Comment: I've edited my other answer.