# Homogeneous generators of a homogeneous ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $I\subset k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ a homogeneous ideal of height $r$. If $I$ can be generated by $r$ elements, can we pick $r$ **homogeneous** elements in $I$ that generate $I$?

**Background**: Let $Y=V_+(I)$ be the corresponding closed subscheme. $Y$ is called a complete intersection if $I$ can be generated by $r$ elements. But it sounds weird to me, since it doesn't ask the generators to be homogeneous, which is not convenient to consider their corresponding hypersurfaces. So I guess we may choose $r$ homogeneous generators for $I$.

Could you provide some help?(prove it or give an counterexample) Thanks!

Comment: Dear Richard, in both this and your [other question posted recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329123/), you've left out quite a bit of context and have posted essentially just the statement of the problem. This is a bit disappointing after you showed some good effort at avoiding this [in our previous interaction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4312847/). Please make some edits to improve your posts.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for pointing out. I have already edited them. By the way, I saw you posted an answer to this question but I havn't read it in detail since not convenient. Do you have any ideas on this problem?  I'd like to learn it if you are willing to share your ideas.

Comment: (for some $j$) $I$ (assumed to be prime) will be the homogeneization of $J$ the height $r$ ideal of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ obtained by sending $x_j$ to $1$. That $J$ is generated by $r$ polynomials, its homogeneization $I'$ is generated by $r$ homogeneous polynomials, $V(I')=V(I)$, and it remains to check that $I'$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you for improving your wishing. I've restored my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $I$ is generated by $r$ elements.
Let $\{f_s\}_{s\in S}$ be a minimal system of homogeneous generators for $I$.
Any relation $\sum g_sf_s=0$ among the $f_s$ must have $g_s\in(x_0,\cdots,x_n)$: if some $g_{s_0}$ has a nonzero constant term, then looking at the $\deg f_{s_0}$ component of the equation, we see that $f_{s_0}$ is in the ideal generated by the other $f_s$ involved.
Now define $I\to k^{\oplus S}$ by $\sum g_sf_s=(g_s(0))_{s\in S}$: this is surjective and does not depend on the representation of an element as $\sum g_sf_s$ by the previous sentence.
This implies that $k^{\oplus S}$ can be generated by $r$ elements, or $r\geq |S|$.
Since every generating set of $I$ must have at least $\operatorname{ht} Y$ elements, we see that $I$ can indeed be generated by $r$ homogeneous elements.